# GAE migrate Java 8 to Java 11; has the data type "Text" done away with?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, migrate, datastore

My GAE app is on Java 8 and I am desperately trying to meet the Jan 30 deadline for migrating to Java 11. Part of that migration process is to point to `com.google.cloud` instead of pointing to `com.google.appengine` in the POM. At present, the app's entity classes use this data type: `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;` which is sourced from here in my POM...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.64</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text]

But the recommended way for Java 11 is to replace the above dependency with this....

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked the latest version (2.18.0) of the above dependency in the Maven repository and it turns out that the type that I have been using (`com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;`) is not present in the "recommended" jar.

[image: google-cloud-datastore]

Am I not looking at the right place? If so, which is the right place? If I am looking at the right place, then what should I replace `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;` with?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I checked a few related stackoverflow questions but could not find an answer. I also checked a few earlier versions of `google-cloud-datastore` for the datatype "Text" but was not able to find it.